# Transition in a form with grid

Tags: css, grid, height, css-transitions, margin

I'm trying to create a grid-form in which there should be two areas that can be shown by clicking ([...]) after "Container" and "Name".
To do this, the height and margin-bottom must be changed using transition.
Unfortunately, I can't create a smooth movement.
But look for yourself:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var url_input = document.getElementById("url_input");
  var name_input = document.getElementById("name_input");
  if (name_input.value == "" && url_input.value !== "") {
    name_input.placeholder = "bitte eintragen";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

document
  .getElementById("container_select")
  .addEventListener("change", fill_input);
function fill_input() {
  // get selected value from pulldown
  var select_value = document.getElementById("container_select").value;
  // set input value with pulldown value
  document.getElementById("container_input").value = select_value;
  console.log("select_value " + select_value);
}
```

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: "";
} /* HIDE ARROW FROM DOPDOWN */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
} /* HIDE ARROW FROM DOPDOWN */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.font_brighter:hover {
  filter: brightness(150%);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --darkest_grey: #1e1e1e;
    --dark_grey: #333333;
    --white: #e0e0e0;
    --black: #000;
    --red: rgb(114, 0, 0);
    --lightred: #ff5458;

    --grey: rgb(130, 130, 130);
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
body {
  background: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 30px;
}
fieldset {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 20px 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: var(--white);
}
.new_entry {
  width: 350px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "container submit " "position color" "hr hr" "name url" "user password" "post_data post_data" "notes notes";
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0em 0.5em;
  background: var(--darkest_grey);
  color: var(--white); /* padding: 1.2em; */
}
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
select:focus,
button:focus {
  background: #444 !important;
}
.new_entry textarea {
  height: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  resize: none;
}
.new_entry button {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
}
.new_entry button:hover {
  filter: brightness(120%);
}
.new_entry input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]),
.new_entry textarea,
.new_entry select,
.new_entry button {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px var(--black);
  background: var(--dark_grey);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: lightslategray;
  padding: 0.2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.new_entry label {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  font-family: serif;
}

/* DISPLAY NONE */
/* 
    .new_entry>div {margin-bottom: .8em;}
    #container {grid-area: container;}
    #delete {grid-area: delete;}
    #delete>label {display: inline;}
    #position {grid-area: position; display: none; }
    #color {grid-area: color; display: none;}
    #name {grid-area: name;}
    #url {grid-area: url;}
    #hr {grid-area: hr; height: 1px; background:var(--grey); display: none;}
    #container_extra:checked~#color,#container_extra:checked~#position,#container_extra:checked~#hr, #item_extra:checked~#password,  #item_extra:checked~#post_data,  #item_extra:checked~#user,  #item_extra:checked~#notes {display: inline;}
    #container_extra:checked~ #container label.checkbox_del, #item_extra:checked~#name label.checkbox_del {display: inline;}
    label.checkbox_del {display: none;}
     #user {grid-area: user;display: none;}
    #password {grid-area: password;display: none;}
    #notes {grid-area: notes;display: none;}
    #post_data {grid-area: post_data;display: none;}
    #submit {grid-area: submit; } 
*/

/* DISPLAY NONE */

/* TRANSITION */
.new_entry > div {
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  background: var(--darkest_grey);
}
#container {
  grid-area: container;
}
#submit {
  grid-area: submit;
}
#position {
  grid-area: position;
}
#color {
  grid-area: color;
}
#hr {
  grid-area: hr;
  height: 1px;
  background: var(--grey);
}
#name {
  grid-area: name;
}
#url {
  grid-area: url;
}
#user {
  grid-area: user;
}
#password {
  grid-area: password;
}
#notes {
  grid-area: notes;
}
#post_data {
  grid-area: post_data;
}
#color,
#position,
#hr,
#password,
#post_data,
#user,
#notes {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.6s linear, margin-bottom 0.4s linear;
  /* transition: margin-bottom 2s; 
        transition: max-height 1s;  */
  /* transition: 
        max-height 0.8s linear, 
        margin-bottom 0.4s   linear; */
}

#container_extra:checked ~ #color,
#container_extra:checked ~ #position,
#container_extra:checked ~ #hr,
#item_extra:checked ~ #password,
#item_extra:checked ~ #post_data,
#item_extra:checked ~ #user,
#item_extra:checked ~ #notes {
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  max-height: 1000px;
  /* transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out 0.5s, margin-bottom 1.3s ease; */
  transition: max-height 1s linear, margin-bottom 0.2s linear;
}

label.checkbox_del {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visible 1.5s;
}
#container_extra:checked ~ #container label.checkbox_del,
#item_extra:checked ~ #name label.checkbox_del {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visible 1.5s;
}
/* TRANSITION */

#submit button {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 1.4em;
  float: right;
  color: var(--white);
}
.icon_more {
  color: var(--grey);
  font-size: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon_del {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
.new_entry input::placeholder {
  color: #ff2727;
}
.new_entry input[type="checkbox"] {
  border: solid 1px var(--black);
  background: var(--red);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.new_entry input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: var(--lightred);
}

#container > input {
  width: 82%;
}
#container > select {
  width: 27.2px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0;
}
#container_select {
  color: transparent;
}
#container_select option {
  color: var(--white);
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 55;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 6px 0 0 6px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="%23E0E0E0"  viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path d="M 0 8 l 2 -3 l 9 9.33 l 8 -9.33 l 2 3 l -10 11 z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>New Entry</a></legend>
  <form method="post" action="./gridform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="new_entry">
    <input type="checkbox" id="container_extra" class="hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" id="item_extra" class="hidden">
    <div tabindex="0" id="container">
      <label for="container_select">Container</label>
      <label class="icon icon_more" for="container_extra">[...]</label>
      <label class="checkbox_del">
        <input type="checkbox" id="del_C" name="icon_del" class="icon_del font_brighter" value="1">
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="container_input" id="container_input" />
      <span class="dropdown"></span>
      <select name="container" id="container_select">
        <option disabled>select Container</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="else">else...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="4" id="submit">
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="position">
      <label for="position_select">Position</label>
      <select name="position" id="position_select">
        <option value="" selected="selected">choose</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="1" id="color">
      <label for="color_select">Color</label>
      <select name="color" id="color_select">
        <option value="a" selected="selected">choose</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="hr"></div>
    <div id="name">
      <label for="name_input">Name</label>
      <label class="icon icon_more" for="item_extra">[...]</label>
      <label class="checkbox_del">
        <input type="checkbox" id="del_C" name="icon_del" class="icon_del font_brighter" value="1">
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name_input" />
    </div>
    <div id="url">
      <label for="url_input">Link</label>
      <input type="text" name="url" id="url_input" />
    </div>
    <div id="user">
      <label for="user_input">User</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user_input" />
    </div>
    <div id="password">
      <label for="password_input">Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password_input" />
    </div>
    <div id="post_data">
      <label for="post_data_text">POST Data</label>
      <textarea name="post_data" id="post_data_text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="notes">
      <label for="notes_text">Notes</label>
      <textarea name="notes" id="notes_text"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

I have played a lot with the duration of the two translations, but haven't found a suitable setting, especially for closing.
Is that even possible?
If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by myself:

`max-height: 1000px;`

With this, the browser calculates the duration for expanding 1000px,
but the menu has only 100px to expand and this is getting fast :-)